# cannot get form element using selenium

Tags: selenium

```
<h6>
    <a href="blah">top</a>
    <form method="post" name="prod" action="blah.jsp>
      <input type="hidden" name="a" value="asdfsd">Jump to product: 
      <input type="text" name="p" size="25"> 
      <a href="#" onclick="document.forms['prod'].submit()">GO</a>
    </form>

    <form method="get" name="catgy" action="cato.jsp">
      <input type="hidden" name="a" value="asdfs3">Jump to category: 
      <input type="text" name="c" size="25"> 
      <a href="#" onclick="document.forms['category'].submit()">GO</a>
    </form>
</h6>
```

Neither this returns element

```
WebElement form = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/h6/form[2]"));
```

nor

```
WebElement form = driver.findElement(By.name("catgy"));
```

Can you please help get the form element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form[name='catgy']"));
```

Comment: that should have worked but it did not. Not sure what is wrong. Is the html itself constructed incorrect in anyway that is preventing from getting the form element?

Comment: actually it worked. Thanks. Not sure why other methods did not work.